# "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved" From Bitbucket Project

Tags: java, eclipse, bitbucket

I have one private Java project in Bitbucket.
When I import this project on my eclipse then I got "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved" this error every time.
Help me to fix for any user who will import this project and not getting this error after import.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you get any more detailed error message, for example in the Build Path settings dialog?

Comment: @Thilo https://postimg.org/image/v2hj6zpo7/ see this url

Comment: Look in the 'Problems' view for more messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your information is not clear to answer but here are some inputs for you.

- When you import the project directly by git clone in eclipse, that might create a problem for build.So after checkout just try to re-import the project to eclipse workspace and build.(It better to look into 'problems' or 'Markers' view of eclipse)
- If it is a Maven project, Sometime Eclipse maven plugin does not work properly. Try disabling the maven nature and add it back, also 'Update project' from maven options.

Do share your actual problem detail for exact help.

Answer (score 0):

Rigth click on your project while open it in eclipse,
Build Path --> Configure Build Path
in the dialog box go to Libraries Tab
Select the file with errors and click edit button in the right hand side
in that dialog box select the last radio button named Workspace default JRE
and click Finish.
Then Run your project.....